# Change build output directory by pragma

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a very big solution that has different output directories for a given project, where I need to rebuild 4 configurations. Each configuration has its own respective x32/64 output directory. My question is, can I add a `#pragma` to specify the output directory within an `#ifdef` to each `#define` configuration?

I am getting very fed up changing the output directory manually, in the project properties, each time I want to rebuild the configuration.

Comment: Just output to ${Configuration} or some other variable and it will change automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Just create 4 solution/project configurations and set a different output directory for each of them.